# Make your own code sample box

Tags: php, css, layout

Is there a simple way to make your own, or is there a plugin to have your own PHP code sample box for presenting your code of an open-source project? I would like to have something like here on Stackoverflow, with colors, to present your code, like:

```php
<?php echo 'test'; ?>
```

If there is no simple way to do is, i'll just make it a download, but It would be handy to have something like this :)

Thanks

Comment: If you don't care about syntax highlighting and line numbers, then you could just use the `<code>` tag - http://jsfiddle.net/ZzX6e/ or if you do - then you could look at a Javascript solution - something like : http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
highlight_string("<?php echo 'test'; ?>");
```

Or there are some libaries that do a better job and other languages.  I've also used [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) in the past.

Also, `highlight_file()`.

Using HTML:

```
echo "<pre>" . highlight_string("<?php echo 'test'; ?>", true) . "</pre>";
```

Comment: Exactly! Has been part of PHP for eons.

Answer (score 0):

Most of these are actually javascript based. SO and many other sites use the js library called **Pettify** to make code blocks look nice. You can find the project at https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/